# Detect vga signals from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, vga

Currently I am working on Ubuntu 12.10. I am using vga2usb device for interacting with other vga devices such as monitors.

Is there any command line utility or any specific command from which I can detect vga signals present or not.

I tired `xrandr` command but it is not useful if vga signals are not active (monitor is in sleep mode).